# I am trying to sync two branches in two different repositories in AWS Codecommit. Is there any way to do the sync in an automated way?

Tags: amazon-web-services, merge, branch, aws-codecommit, multiple-repositories

Using Codecommit to store the repositories. I have one branches in RepoA and one branch in RepoB. I am trying to sync the changes made in RepoA's branch into RepoB's branch but in an automated way. Is there any way I can use Lambda or codebuild containers to do so?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on sync? Are two branches are totally different? Or one is always ahead of other and you want to sync them?

Comment: The branch in RepoA is maintained by developer and before I deploy it into QA from the repoB I want to see what changes they have made from the previous version so I need the repoB's branch to be synced with RepoA's branch. To answer your question Repo A's branch will always be one step ahead before syncing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so there is any out-of-the-box solution from CodeCommit for this. I also don't think having 2 different repos, one for developer and one for deployment is a good design.

Coming back to answer your question, you can sync the branches in 2 different repos through a script, and call the same from Lambda. However, what you have to take care over here is, are all the parameters to execute this script are well within Lambda's limits?

Assuming the sequence of operation is something like :

1. Clone repo A.
2. Checkout branch A.
3. Add new remote "origin2" as repo B to repo A cloned copy.
4. Pull from origin2 branch A.
5. Push to origin2 branch A.

I would say, better to trigger a Container with required script and details/parameters to execute the script.

If you already have any CI setup such as Jenkins/Bamboo, it will be a lot easier.